# Fatal error: Uncaught PayPalHttp\HttpException

Tags: php, paypal

Fatal error:  Uncaught PayPalHttp\HttpException: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"} in /home/smmtopse/public_html/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php:224
Stack trace:
#0 /home/smmtopse/public_html/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php(107): PayPalHttp\HttpClient->parseResponse(Object(PayPalHttp\Curl))
#1 /home/smmtopse/public_html/vendor/paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk/lib/PayPalCheckoutSdk/Core/AuthorizationInjector.php(40): PayPalHttp\HttpClient->execute(Object(PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AccessTokenRequest))
#2 /home/smmtopse/public_html/vendor/paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk/lib/PayPalCheckoutSdk/Core/AuthorizationInjector.php(32): PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AuthorizationInjector->fetchAccessToken()
#3 /home/smmtopse/public_html/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php(71): PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AuthorizationInjector->inject(Object(PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest))
#4 /home/smmtopse/public_html/app/controller/addfunds.php(189): PayP in /home/smmtopse/public_html/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php on line 224

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. You can not just dump an error message and a stack trace here, and then expect people could tell you what exactly the issue might be, based on just that. `invalid_client` probably means that you either supplied a wrong client id, or did not send it in the correct format/under the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

There are exactly two possible reasons for an invalid_client error when attempting to obtain an access_token.

1. You are using or transmitting wrong REST App API credentials. Obtain a new clientid and secret from the "sandbox" or "live' tab of [PayPal Developer](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications).

2. You are using sandbox credential in live mode, or live credentials in sandbox mode. The two environments are completely separate, and a clientid+secret from one will never work in the other.